# Drawing scattered plot using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to draw a scattered plot using python. I have these two 2D arrays and I want to show them in same scattered plot.

```
[[69, 72], [72, 80], [74, 81], [70, 75], [78, 87], [71, 73], [69, 70], [71, 77]]
[[78, 139], [80, 158], [85, 154], [72, 105], [84, 148], [74, 87], [73, 106], [71, 109]]
```

How can I do this? I want points of different arrays to be of different colors.
I'm using python 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *Matplotlib* [scatter](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_symbol.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-symbol-py) tool to graph your points. Here is how you'll do it, applying their example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib    

array1 = [[69, 72], [72, 80], [74, 81], [70, 75], [78, 87], [71, 73], [69, 70], [71, 77]]
array2 = [[78, 139], [80, 158], [85, 154], [72, 105], [84, 148], [74, 87], [73, 106], [71, 109]]

x1 = [point[0] for point in array1]
y1 = [point[1] for point in array1]
x2 = [point[0] for point in array2]
y2 = [point[1] for point in array2]
s = 20

plt.scatter(x1, y1, s, c="r", alpha=0.5, marker=r'o',
            label="Array 1")
plt.scatter(x2, y2, s, c="b", alpha=0.5, marker=r'o',
            label="Array 2")
plt.xlabel("X")
plt.ylabel("Y")
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.show()
```

This will give you this nice looking graph:

[image: Scatter Plot]